# how to display list items one by one using next and previous buttons with javascript, no jquery please

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'm learning javascript and want to make a very simple slider to understand how things work and use it in my project.

here is the code in codepen and here too

desired result:

1. div1 is inline by default as first slide.
2. user press next, will hide div1 then show div2 and so on.
3. user press previous button, will do the opposite.
4. user press next at the end or previous at the start of array will loop.

thanks for any help.

https://codepen.io/Willpower_7/pen/gOvJaLe

```js
var listItems = document.getElementById("slides-container-li").children;

function clickNext() {
  listItems[0].style.display = "none";
  listItems[1].style.display = "inline";
}

function clickPrevious() {
  listItems[0].style.display = "inline";
  listItems[1].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slides-container-li {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.div3 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.btn-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <li class="slides-container-li" id="slides-container-li">
    <div class="div1">div1</div>
    <div class="div2">div2</div>
    <div class="div3">div3</div>
  </li>
</div>

<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="Previous-btn" id="Previous-btn" onclick="clickPrevious()">Previous</button>
  <button class="slide-btn" id="slide-btn" onclick="clickNext()">next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an infinity looping slider and will work whatever the count of sliders, please check.

```js
var listItems = document.getElementById("slides-container-li").children;

let currentIndex = 0;



function clickNext() {
  //console.log(currentIndex >= listItems.length - 1);
  if (currentIndex >= listItems.length - 1) {
    currentIndex = -1;
  }
  [...listItems].forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none')
  listItems[++currentIndex].style.display = "inline"
  ;
  //console.log('after increment', currentIndex)
  }

function clickPrevious() {
    if (currentIndex <= 0) {
    currentIndex = listItems.length;
  }
  [...listItems].forEach(item => item.style.display = 'none')
  listItems[--currentIndex].style.display = "inline";
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.slides-container-li {
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: orange;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.div3 {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  display: none;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.btn-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: lightgray;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <li class="slides-container-li" id="slides-container-li">
      <div class="div1">div1</div>
      <div class="div2">div2</div>
      <div class="div3">div3</div>
    </li>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="Previous-btn" id="Previous-btn" onclick="clickPrevious()">Previous</button>

    <button class="slide-btn" id="slide-btn" onclick="clickNext()">next</button>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wow, this work exactly as I wanted. now it's time to try to understand the code. ah. don't know many things in it. things I don't know: 

1- why length -1 ? 
2- why that line start with [... ?
3- for Each .  Ithink I can easily find this online and learn it. 
4- => . I checked this before but apparently I forgot. 

thank you.

Comment: Thanks, Simple I add a variable to indicate the current slide index called "currentIndex", then when I click next button it will be increased by one if click prev button it will decrease by one, in case of next button if we reached to last slider we need to return to first slider if we click next, so I re-initialize the currentIndex variable by -1, so when use it as ++currentIndex it will be equal 0 ( the first slide ), in case of prev button, if we on the first slide and we click the prev button we need the last slider ( which it's index = slider length - 1 ).

Comment: great info, this will help me a lot to study and understand the code. thank you very much. and have a nice day.

Comment: You are welcome, have a good day too.

Comment: I have a question. I might be a little annoying but please be patient with me.
 
- listItems is an array, right? if so, then why do we need to put it in an array again [...listItems]? 

I know the => arrow function has an array in its syntax, but as I said, the listItems is already an array. am I wrong?

thank you for your time. 
Please let me know if you don't mind me asking more questions if needed.

Comment: Never mind, listItems is not an array, it's a "NodeList", it hasn't forEach function on it, so if you try listItems.forEach(() => {...}) it will give an error "forEach is not a function" because it is undefined, so [...itemlist] convert it to an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245792/discussion-between-willpower-7-and-mina).

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this , you have to take one runtime variable & change it's value on onclick function

```
let currentPageNum = 0;

function clickNext() {
  if(listItems.length-1 != currentPageNum){
    listItems[currentPageNum].style.display = "none";
    listItems[currentPageNum+1].style.display = "inline";
    currentPageNum = currentPageNum+1;
  }
}

function clickPrevious() {
  if(currentPageNum != 0){
    listItems[currentPageNum-1].style.display = "inline";
    listItems[currentPageNum].style.display = "none";
    currentPageNum = currentPageNum-1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this way but didn't work for me. I just tried your code and didn't work too. thanks anyway.

Comment: works perfectly fine for me , also check in your codepen , please make sure you are not missing any thing

Comment: Sorry, may bad. yes, it works fine but it doesn't loop. thank you.